# Is it Possible to give image animation in Mac?

Tags: image, macos, animation, core-animation

I want to give image animation in mac application like i have array of images and i want to animate that images so how can i give that animation in Mac application.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: can you please be more specific,about what type of animation you want!

Comment: Refer this question..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031285/core-animation-animating-an-array-of-images

Hope its helpful..

Comment: In case you can use `NSTimer` for that. [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Comment: You're going to have to provide a better description of what you want to do if you want help. Are you talking about frame-based animation, where the system cycles between a series of images like a flip book?

Comment: yes i want animation like flip book same as pageviewcontroller in iOS